# TSQL Window Function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, window-functions

I have a table with three columns:

```
Survey   QuestionName   SurveyQuestion     SurveyAnswer
1859     Satisfied?     1                  Yes
1859     Comments?      2                  Happy with outcome, thanks
1859     Phone Number?  3                  Not Answered
2000     Satisfied?     1                  No
2000     Comments?      2                  Rep was a d1ck. 
2000     Phone Number?  3                  5166569999
```

What I want to end up with is a table that looks like this (Note: SurveyQuestion #3 is not needed)

```
Survey   SurveyAnswer1    SurveyAnswer2     
1859     Yes              Happy with outcome, thanks
2000     No               Rep was a d1ck.
```

I just can't think of how to do this... I've tried several ways including `LEAD`/`LAG`, but can't get it to work... I think I just need someone to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's four columns ;)

You can use the old aggregate-as-crosstab chestnut:

```
select   Survey,
         SurveyAnswer1 = max(iif(SurveyQuestion = 1, SurveyAnswer, null)),
         SurveyAnswer2 = max(iif(SurveyQuestion = 2, SurveyAnswer, null))
from     YourTable
where    SurveyQuestion != 3
group by Survey
```